# MPI_Dims_create throws error on remote machine

Tags: c++, openmpi

I'm trying to set up a cartesian grid as a first step in my algorithm. On my local machine (OS X with clang), my code runs. On the research cluster (Linux with GNU), I get the following error.

```
$mpirun -n 4 ./test.exe
[shas0137:67495] *** An error occurred in MPI_Dims_create
[shas0137:67495] *** reported by process [3694788609,1]
[shas0137:67495] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[shas0137:67495] *** MPI_ERR_DIMS: invalid topology dimension
[shas0137:67495] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[shas0137:67495] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
[shas0137:67491] 3 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt / mpi_errors_are_fatal
[shas0137:67491] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
```

Setting the "orte_base_help_aggregate" parameter just repeats the error message 4 times (once for each process)

Most MPI routines have a list of error codes in the documentation, but MPI_ERR_DIMS isn't listed for [MPI_Dims_create](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Dims_create.html)

Version Details: Local

```
$ mpic++ -v
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Version Details: Research Cluster

```
$ mpic++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/curc/sw/gcc/6.1.0/bin/g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/curc/sw/gcc/6.1.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-6.1.0/configure --prefix=/curc/sw/gcc/6.1.0 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go --disable-multilib --with-tune=intel
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.1.0 (GCC)
```

### MCVE

(or as close as I could get to verifiable given that this only happens on some configurations)

```
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Status st;
    MPI_Comm comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;

    MPI_Comm grid_comm;

    int size;
    int err = MPI_Comm_size(comm, &size);

    //Error handling
    if (err != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << size << std::endl;

    //This call throws the error
    int dims[3];
    err = MPI_Dims_create(size, 3, dims);

    //Error handling
    if (err != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        return 2;
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TLDR

I declared but did not initialize the dim array. On my local machine, I just got a clean chunk of memory coincidentally.

## Why is this important?

I missed that this was important in part because I missed that dims was both an input and an output parameter. I assumed that as an output parameter, any values in dims would be overwritten by the MPI routine.

The original documentation that I consulted ([from MPICH](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Dims_create.html)) was very brief.

> ## MPI_Dims_create
>
> ### Input/Output Parameters
>
> dims
>
> integer array of size ndims specifying the number of nodes in
> each dimension. **A value of 0 indicates that MPI_Dims_create should
> fill in a suitable value.** (emphasis mine)

i.e. Non-zero values will not be overwritten by the routine.

More information is available on [MPI Forum MPI Documentation](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node134.html):

> ## 6.5.2. Cartesian Convenience Function: MPI_DIMS_CREATE
>
> (...)
> The caller may further constrain the operation of this routine by
> specifying elements of array dims. If dims[i] is set to a positive
> number, the routine will not modify the number of nodes in dimension
> i; only those entries where dims[i] = 0 are modified by the call.
>
> Negative input values of dims[i] are erroneous. (...)

In short, on the research cluster, the values in the uninitialized dims array were either negative or larger than the number of nodes I was trying to assign.